# How to sum up Y values for bins instead of averaging?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe `data`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = pd.read_table(StringIO("""time_diff  avg_trips_per_day
631         1.0
231         1.0
431         1.0
7031        1.0
17231       1.0
20000       20.0
21000       15.0
22000       10.0"""), delim_whitespace=True)
```

I create a barchart as folows:

```
import seaborn as sns
data['timegroup'] = pd.qcut(data['time_diff'], 3)
sns.barplot(x='timegroup', y='avg_trips_per_day', data=data)
```

Currently it takes the values of `avg_trips_per_day` for each bin (`timegroup`) and calculates a mean `avg_trips_per_day`.
However, I want to sum-up the values of `avg_trips_per_day` for each bin `timegroup` instead of using mean. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the estimator parameter of [barplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
sns.barplot(x='timegroup', y='avg_trips_per_day', data=data, estimator=sum)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. By the way in my case the lower bound of the first bin is negative for some reason, while in the data I do not have negative numbers. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Dinosaurius I am afraid not. It returns an IntervalIndex and those are not mutable. Probably you'll need to construct the whole index from scratch for that.